# DNS entries required to get test.example.com to respond to pinging?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, linode

What DNS entries do I need to setup for `test.example.com` to respond to pinging?

Here's my DNS entries as I've setup through Linode:

[image]

Comment: If you're not going to bother obfuscating your screenshots, you may as well use your domain in the question. Or at least make it clear that `example.com` is really the domain in your screenshot if you don't want your domain name indexed.

Comment: I didn't intend to. Force of habit made me generalize the question. `example.com` is the one address that I can site that won't be porn in 5 years. I can't say the same for my own domain.

Comment: Is it possible that either the server is configured to not respond to pings or that there is some form of firewall preventing its response from reaching the destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `A` record for `test` that you already have in there is the one you need.

It's working - you might not have waited long enough for the DNS.

```
Pinging test.wendler.mobi [97.107.134.245] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 97.107.134.245: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=51
Reply from 97.107.134.245: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=51
```

Comment: Just to clarify - pinging is, in absolutally no way, related to DNS. It just so happens that DNS *may* form part of the `ping` command, but apart from that, they're two totally different concepts.

Comment: Huh. It's been over 24 hours. I guess I'll keep waiting.

Comment: I wonder if google's DNS servers update less frequently than others.

Comment: @iftrue `8.8.8.8` seems to have it...

Comment: Okay, seems to be up now. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance you actually meant `test.example.com` literally, you would have to speak to IANA about this one.  See http://www.example.com and [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) for gory details and a cure for insomnia :-)

Otherwise like Shane said, patience is a virtue when dealing with DNS (at least as patient as the negative result cache time).